# MVC pass model back to controller with data prefilled

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model, controller, sql-update

I have come across this issue a number of times now. I have solved the issue in different ways but always feel like there is a better way to handle the situation. Searching for a solution (best practice) has yielded nada. Hoping to get some sage advice.

The scenario goes like this: I'm building a MVC4 web application. I'm passing a complex Model to my view. For example:

```
public class Uat 
{
    public int UatId { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TestCase> TestCases { get; set; }
    public UatStatus Status { get; set; }
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public string StatusChangeDate { get; set; }
    public string ProductVersion { get; set; }
    public string Introduction { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
}
```

I want to pass this model to a view and have the user update only certain pieces of the model. In the current instance I'm dealing with, the user is updating two fields of a child object (TestCase). The TestCase object looks like this:

```
 public class TestCase
 {
    [Key]
    public int TestCaseId { get; set; }
    public int UatId { get; set; }
    public virtual Uat Uat { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Step> Steps { get; set; }
    public TestCaseStatus Status { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

The user is only editing TestCase.Comment and TestCase.Status. Most of the other values have already been set by the admin user. So I pass a Uat object to my view which looks like this:

```
@Model ClientPortal.Models.Uat

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Uat";
}

<h2>Uat</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("UatEvalution", "Client")) 
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<div>
    @{var iteration = 0;}
    @foreach (var testCase in Model.TestCases)
    {
        <div class="well">
        <span class="testCaseTitle"><h4>@testCase.Title</h4></span> 

        <br />
        <br />

        <ol style="margin-left:40px">
            @foreach (var step in testCase.Steps)
            {
                <li>@step.Description</li>
            }
        </ol>

        <br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="TestCases[@iteration].Status" value="2" />Approve &nbsp; &nbsp; 
        <input type="checkbox" name="TestCases[@iteration].Status" value="1" />Deny 

        <br />

        <span><textarea name="TestCases[@iteration].Comment"></textarea></span>


        @{iteration = iteration + 1;
    }
        </div>
    }
</div>
<input type="submit" />
}
```

My controllerAction looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UatEvalution(Uat uat)
    {
        //process data
        //Update(uat);
        //SaveChanges();
    }
```

The issue is, my uat object in the controller only has TestCases data. Everything else is null or 0. The TestCases inside the Uat only have data for Comment and Status, everything else is null or 0. So if I try to run an Update on this model, I get the error: An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. I've looked into this and this makes sense to me. But to remedy this, I have done one of two things in the past:

1. I create a bunch of hidden fields in the view to populate the rest of the properties in the model, so that when the model is passed back to the Controller, all the data is filled out the same way it was when I pulled it from the db; except it has the changes made by the user.
2. I re-pull the TestCase entry from the data base, make the appropriate changes to that entry and then SaveChanges().

Both of these solutions feel ugly to me, and I'm sure I'm doing something incorrectly. While this solves this issue for me in the past, it causes my views to get cluttered with hidden fields, or I end up making too many requests to the db. My applications are small, so these workarounds don't have much of an effect now, but I really want to get in the habit of best practices. Any help would be greatly appreciated as it always is from the SO community. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is why you need a viewmodel that represents either full or part of your entity. One of the benefits of using a viewmodel is to prevent over or under posting. Your situation is a perfect example of that. You only need to update a few fields of your entity, which most of the time make sense actually, and so you do not need to return the rest of the fields to the view. Not even having them as hidden fields, just for the sake of having the values posted back and save in the database. If you just need two of the fields then create a model for it, something like:

```
public class TestCaseModel
{
    public int TestCaseId { get; set; }
    public TestCaseStatus Status { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

Since you will be going the viewmodel route, you might as well need to have a viewmodel for your `Uat` entity. Or the best approach is have a **flat** model like this:

```
    public class TestCaseInputModel
    {
        public int UatId{ get; set; } // for reference
        public int TestCaseId { get; set; }
        public TestCaseStatus Status { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
    }
```

Then just add the necessary fields or those fields that you want to "show", meaning that you do not expect to have inputs. You then have to map all the "input" fields of your model back to your entity. Something like:

```
var testCaseEntity = retrieve_from_db();
testCaseEntity.UatId = input.UatId;
testCaseEntity.Status = input.Status;
testCaseEntity.Comment  = input.Comment;
```

In addition, you can use auto mapping tools to get the values from your model back to your entity. That is the cleanest way you can do it, IMO.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation von. ViewModels have helped me in the past. There are times when I feel like I'm having to hack things, when, in reality I guess it's just how mvc works. I appreciate your feedback!

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you choose to have viewmodels as well in your current project @nycfdtd.